# How to find relationships of 2 types of nodes in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j

I have two types of nodes stored in Neo4j db: Person and Group. I defined a relationship "IN" between Person and Group: `(p:Person)-[:IN]->(g:Group)`.

The question is given 2 Person nodes, how can I find the relationships between them?

I know I can use Cypher queries such as

```
MATCH (p1:Person{pid: '11231'})-[:IN]->(g:Group)<-[:IN]-(p2:Person{pid: '1231231'}) 
RETURN p1,p2,g;
```

But how can I describe a multi-hop relationship so that Neo4j can find links between two not directly linked Person nodes?  I don't know how many hops are required to link these two Person nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below Cypher query:

```
MATCH (p1:Person{pid: '11231'})-[:IN*]-(p2:Person{pid: '1231231'}) return p1,p2;
```

Note: the * in the relationship IN does the trick.

However, this is inefficient approach and you should limit the number of hops like this:

```
MATCH (p1:Person{pid: '11231'})-[:IN*1..5]-(p2:Person{pid: '1231231'}) return p1,p2;
```

More relationship match pattern can be found in the cypher refcard patterns section

https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-refcard/current/

Comment: The trick works! But I want the query also return Group nodes involved in the relationship, is there a way? Thank you.

Comment: @tuo Yes, you can do this. You'll need to add a path variable to the match `MATCH path=(p1:Person ...`, and use the following RETURN: `RETURN p1, p2, FILTER(node in NODES(path) WHERE node:Group) as groups`

Comment: Thank you @InverseFalcon. It solves my problem. I want to mark your answer as the correct answer too but I can only upvote it :)